# Get geometry from coordinates

Tags: postgresql, geometry, coordinates, postgis-1.5

I have a table with geometry column called point, saved in SRID 4326. I want to get the geometry by its coordinates, but something didn't work. I suspect database configuration or something.

Here is what I do

```
select point from geom_data limit 1
```

And I get "0101000060E610000000000020558A5EC0000000C0F3B8424000B0CFCFA4717342"

This as text is

```
select AsText(point) from geom_data where point = '0101000060E610000000000020558A5EC0000000C0F3B8424000B0CFCFA4717342'
```

And the result is "POINT(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668)"

Trying this

```
select * from geom_data where ST_Contains(point, ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668)'))
```

Didn't give a result. Tried this

```
select ST_PointFromText('POINT(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668)', 4326)
```

and get "0101000020E61000000F000020558A5EC0040000C0F3B84240" which is different.

Selecting within bounding box didn't worked either

```
select * from geom_data where
st_x(point) >= '-122.161445617670' AND st_x(point) <= '-122.161445617679'
AND st_y(point) >= '37.444938659660' AND st_y(point) <= '37.444938659669'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can and should use the tags to specify what GIS/database environment this pertains to, e.g. PostGIS.

Comment: Didn't know that. Added tags. The database is version 8.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to your question really. First, the binary discrepancy between the point in the database and the point you supply, and second, trying to do a spatial query on the points.

To address the discrepancy problem, it turns out that the point stored in your database is a 2D+M point. Running this query:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsEWKT('0101000060E610000000000020558A5EC0000000C0F3B8424000B0CFCFA4717342');
```

Yields:

```sql
SRID=4326;POINTM(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668 1336176082171)
```

This is fine for spatial queries, because PostGIS will ignore the M parameter, which is used as a general per-vertex floating point attribute. Originally it stood for "measure", but it can represent anything you fancy.

The second problem can be solved in two ways. You can use the `ST_Equals()` function:

```sql
SELECT ST_Equals(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINTM(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668 1336176082171)'), ST_PointFromText('POINT(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668)', 4326));
```

or

```sql
SELECT ST_Equals(ST_AsEWKT('0101000060E610000000000020558A5EC0000000C0F3B8424000B0CFCFA4717342'), ST_PointFromText('POINT(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668)', 4326));
```

Both of which return true.

Or use `ST_Within()` if there is some tolerance needed:

```sql
SELECT ST_DWithin(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINTM(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668 1336176082171)'), ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668)'), 1.0)
```

Notice here I'm using the `geography` type, this is so you can specify the distance in metres on unprojected data. If you just used the `geometry` type, you'd have to specify the tolerance in degrees, which is fraught and generally of not much use, or project the data first which is potentially inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

To select all the points within a bounding box use the [ST_Within](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_Within.html) function of PostGIS and create a bounding box with [ST_MakeEnvelope](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_MakeEnvelope.html):

```
SELECT * FROM geom_data WHERE ST_WITHIN(point, ST_MakeEnvelope(-122, 37, -121, 38, 4326));
```

In your case it is also possible to use the [@ operator](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_Geometry_Contained.html), that makes use of the geometry indexes (and thus it is faster), but only considers the bounding boxes of the geometries:

```
SELECT * FROM geom_data WHERE point @ ST_MakeEnvelope(-122, 37,-121, 38, 4326);
```

Comment: Ok, that is working, but if there a way to do it more precisely? I mean that specifying a bounding box can return 5 points (all points in the box). Is there a way to specify the exact point by its coordinates?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve. If you know already the coordinates of the point, why do you want to select it?

Comment: To get other information from the table that is not recorded in the point object, but on the same row.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE geom_data ( id serial );

-- i use 'point' for the name of the geometry column, but remember that 
-- a common practice is call it 'geom' or 'the_geom'
SELECT addgeometrycolumn ('geom_data', 'point', 4326, 'POINT', 2);

INSERT INTO geom_data (point) (SELECT ST_POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(-122.161445617676 37.444938659668)', 4326));
```

and you only need the coordinate x and the coordinate y of your points:

```
SELECT st_x(point), st_y(point) from geom_data;
```

Comment: What I want is the reverse operation by specifying the x and y coordinates to get the geometry (in my case point). There is a difference in the blob (see above) when creating point from text and that already saved in the database. I tried with adding z too (assume this is 0), but it didn't helped.